# Flask web page not redirecting after executnig a shell script

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I have a python script using the flask framework to handle the backend for the webpage that I am developing now.
In the home page user would upload a file and when clicked on submit it will route to a function where the parameters would be retrieved using requests.get and passed to the script. The script would start docker container and execute commands.

Note: Script execution time depends on the file that is being uploaded, it could range anywhere between 15 mins to a day or more.

Once the script is executed the current function would redirect to a another function which would render a html file. That html file will have a link. When clicked the user should be able to download the file.

```
    from flask import Flask,request,render_template,send_file,redirect
    import os
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
```

```
import checkPort as cp
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
import user_info
app = Flask(__name__)


available_port=0


#create a container direcotry for the current user 
dir_name=""
def createDir(name):
    dir_name="containers/container_"+name;
    print(dir_name)
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
        os.mkdir(dir_name)
    upload_dir="/uploads"
    if not os.path.exists(dir_name+upload_dir):
        os.mkdir(dir_name+upload_dir)
        return dir_name+upload_dir
    return 
    
def get_user_dir():
    return dir_name
    


      
def run_script(zip_file_name,folder_name,file_name,absolute_path_dir,available_port):
     print("Running the shell script")
     dockerweb_script_path=os.getenv('GRIDPRO_REPO') +"/DockerWeb/runDockerFlow.sh"
     script_output =  subprocess.check_output([dockerweb_script_path,zip_file_name, folder_name, file_name, absolute_path_dir, available_port])
     print(script_output)
     '''qprocess=QProcess()
     qprocess.start("sh",["-c",dockerweb_script_path+" "+ zip_file_name+" "+folder_name+" "+file_name+" "+absolute_path_dir+" "+available_port +"> log.txt "])     
     qprocess.waitForStarted()
     qprocess.waitForFinished()
     print("Done")
     print(qprocess.readAllStandardOutput())
     #print(qprocess.readAllStandardError())'''
     
#only files with the file extension .zip or .tar is allowed  
def check_file_extension(file_ext):
    file_extensions=['zip','fra','tar.xz','tar,gz']
    if(file_ext in file_extensions):
        return True
    return False

#run this function when the session terminates
def clean_up_tasks():
    os.system("echo running post task clean up ")



#confgiure the max size of the file that is being uploaded. Size is restricted to 500mb
app.config["MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH"] = 500*1024*1024

#homepage 
@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


#once the file is uploaded and submit button is clicked from the homepage,
#the action redirects the url to /upload where the file extension of 
#the uploaded file is checked. If it is zip or tar it is uploaded and the script is ran with file name as an argument
#file name is taken in as argument by the shell scrpit is to unzip it

@app.route('/upload',methods=['POST','GET'])
def on_click_upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f=request.files['file']
        if check_file_extension(f.filename.split(".")[-1]):
            fname=request.form.get("topology_fname")
            user_info.username=request.form.get("username")
            #print(username)
            full_path_to_dir=createDir(user_info.username)
           # print(full_path_to_dir)
            #configure the upload directory to which the file needs to be uploaded in the server 
            app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]=full_path_to_dir
            #app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]="container_ransom/uploads/"
            k= "file uploaded successfully"
            f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],secure_filename(f.filename)))
            for i in range(8000,9000):
                if cp.check_port(i):
                    available_port=i
                    break   

            #run_script(f.file_name,fname)
            if available_port != 0:
                print(available_port)
                run_script(f.filename,f.filename.split(".")[0],fname,"container_"+user_info.username,str(available_port))
            else:
                print("no port available")
        else:
            k= "unable to upload file of extension "+f.filename.split(".")[-1]+". upload files with extension 'zip, tar'"
    return redirect('/downloadFile')

    #return render_template('sayHello.html')
@app.route('/downloadFile',methods=['GET','POST'])
def downloadFile():
    return render_template("download.html")

@app.route('/returnFile',methods=['GET','POST'])
def download():
    print("download()start")
    return send_file("containers/container_"+user_info.username+"/output_files.zip",as_attachment=True)
    



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1',port=4455,debug=True,threaded=True)
```

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width","initial-scale=1.0" />
     <title> File Uploader </title>
    </head>
 <body bgcolor="#afafaf">
      <form action="/upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      Upload file and click button
      <br>
     <label for="user_name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="user_name" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username">
      <input type="file" name="file"/>
     <label for="topology_file">The name of the topology file to run ggrid on:</label>
    <input type="text" id="topology_fle" name="topology_fname" placeholder="Name of the topology file">
      <br>
      <input type="submit" />
      
      </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

download.html

```
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width","initial-scale=1.0" />
     <title> File Uploader </title>
    </head>
 <body bgcolor="#afafaf">
       <a href="/returnFile" target= "blank"> <button class="btn btn-default">Download</button></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

The issue I am facing currently is that once the output file has been genrated and copied to host machine, it is supposed to redirect me to that page. It isn't redirecting for now. I can't think why nor understand why it isn't

Would appreciate if you could help me sort this out. I am not very much familiar with web development and flask framework

Comment: If the `/upload` endpoint is taking 15 minutes to a day to respond, the browser will timeout and the redirect response will never be received. Does returning `redirect('/downloadFile')` immediately work?

Comment: Yes returning immediately works. It redirect me to the page

Comment: But doesn't when it executes the script. Is there a way to fix it. Like set the browser timeout or something

Comment: Unfortunately, this becomes a non-trivial problem to solve.
You could try looking into WebSockets for long-lived connections https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/server.html
Or change your approach entirely, like opting for a "status" page instead of an automatic redirect.